# git pull conflicts when pulling a non current branch

Tags: git

I have a problem when manipulating git pull.
Consider I have 2 branches on my remote (origin) repository : A and B.

The remote B branch is ahead of the local B branch by 1 commit.

This additional commit (on the remote B branch) just add a new file, say "newfile".

In my local branch A, I have a file "newfile" and its content is different from the one of the remote B branch.

Then, I run this commands:

```
git checkout A
git pull origin B:B
```

I can see the following behavior: the branch B is updated as I expected. B has been fast-forwarded, and then contains "newfile". But I also have a conflict on "newfile". and in my current directory, the file "newfile" contains the conflicts markers.

Why is there a conflict while the merge has already been done ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I misunderstood the semantics of git pull. I thought that :

```
git pull origin B:B
```

meant :

```
fetch the remote B 
         + 
merge the remote B into the local B
```

I realize that it means :

```
fetch the remote B and updates (if fast-forward is possible)  the local B
             +
merge the remote B into the local branch
```

In fact git pull will always make its merge into the local branch, independently of the refspec.

In other words, pull = fetch + merge. The update of the local B branch is done by "fetch", and the conflict is generated by the following merge operation (into the local branch).

Answer (score 0):

When you do a pull, (by default) it gets everything that it can without overwriting any changes you have made. Anything that it could not get because it would have had to modify your edit is considered a conflict. Conflicts need to be resolved manually, or you can undo your changes and do another pull. Once you complete your merge, you can do a push to commit your change.

This is the default behavior because think of how bad this could be if it didn't do this- your changes could be blown away by a pull without your permission.

Comment: when I run "git pull origin B:B" I expect that the remote branch B be merged into my local branch B. In this case, fast-forward merge is possible, and it is successfully done ! But why there is still a conflict ? The conflict is between the remote B version of "newfile" and the local A (my current branch) version of "newfile". But I don't expected that the current branch (A) will interfert in the pull operation. why is it the case ?